# Soft Plus activation function with large values

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I have implemented Soft Plus for my training research with GoLang.

$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
$$

Implementation:

```
func SoftPlus(x float64) float64 {                                                     
    return (float64(1) / (float64(1) + math.Exp(-x)))
}
```

`math.Exp(-x)` returns 0 or infinity with large values of `x` (actually +/-1000 and greater/lesser, if negative)

The first solution which came to my mind is:

$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-1*(1/x)}}
$$

But it seems too naive and still has very low precision of probability.

Does exist any kind of Soft Plus optimization for such a case?

Comment: I am not familiar with the code you are using but for large positive values of x the function you are computing should be close to 1.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, yep I know but in a way it implemented and with large incoming values it returns 0 or 1, not close but exactly 0 or 1. That what I want to solve in a smarter way than I did it now.

Comment: You probably have a coding problem. I don't know how to debug your code.